# Correct way of Binary Search Algorithm

Tags: java, binary-search

I just learned about the Binary Search algorithm and I tried to implement it. I have used a few test cases and it seems to work fine. However, when I checked on GeeksforGeeks, there are quite a few differences in the way they handled the indexing. Can anyone shed some lights on whether my implementation is good  or not. And if not, how would it fail to work?

Here's my code:

```
static int binarySearch(int arr[], int i, int r, int x) {

    if(r > 1) {
        int middle = r/2;

        if(arr[middle] == x) {
            return middle;
        }

        if(arr[middle] > x) {
            return binarySearch(arr, i, middle, x);
        }else {
            return binarySearch(arr, middle, r+1, x);
        }
    }       

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: If the code seems to work fine, then please consider posting to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Why can't `r == 1`? What if you had a one item array? You return -1 always

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks, I will post it there. Didn't know there was a specific code review stack. And you're right, should have been >= 1

Comment: @cricket_007 You made an excellent point. I just tested it for an array of size 1 and it fails, even when I add r>=1.

Comment: There are several correct ways to implement binary search. For example you can iterate or recurse. You can maintain high and low separately, or you can maintain midpoint and delta. These alone give you four implementations. There is no one 'correct way'.

Comment: With regards to testing, also consider an empty/null array and negative/out of bounds index numbers

Comment: @nTuply change it to r >= 0 since the index of an array starts at 0

Comment: You're not using your variable `i` in your code. If it is the low index to search within, then you're not calculating the middle index correctly.

Comment: Here is the OpenJDK  implementation for binary search. Just in case you want to compare your version and investigate a bit more 
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/Arrays.java#L1867

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that our function is going to do a binary search on the subarray `arr[l..r]` (inclusive). Here, `r - l + 1` is the length of this subarray and when it's not a positive number (or `r < l`), we don't have a valid subarray and we can't search for anything, so the function stops the recursion and returns -1.

You know, we always make two subarrays with (almost) equal length. So, `middle = r/2` is not correct and `middle = (l + r) / 2` is correct. The new subarrays are `arr[l..middle-1]` and `arr[middle+1..r]`. We divide the subarray after checking its middle element, so these two subarrays should not contain the middle index as you see.

Now, we can rewrite your code.

```
static int binarySearch(int arr[], int l, int r, int x) {
    if (r >= l) {
        int middle = (l + r) / 2; //int middle = l + (r - l) / 2; for avoiding integer overflow
        if(arr[middle] == x)
            return middle;
        if (arr[middle] > x)
            return binarySearch(arr, l, middle - 1, x);
        else
            return binarySearch(arr, middle + 1, r, x);
    }       
    return -1;
}
```

And this is a non-recursive version of binary search algorithm. Usually, it can work slightly faster.

```
static int binarySearch2(int arr[], int l, int r, int x) {
    while (r >= l) {
        int middle = (l + r) / 2; //int middle = l + (r - l) / 2; for avoiding integer overflow
        if (arr[middle] == x)
            return middle;
        if (arr[middle] > x)
            r = middle - 1;
        else
            l = middle + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Don't forget to sort your array before calling these functions.
Suppose that `n` is the length of the given array.
For 0-based arrays, the correct form of calling the functions is this:

```
binarySearch(arr, 0, n - 1, x);
```

and

```
binarySearch2(arr, 0, n - 1, x);
```

For 1-based arrays, the correct form of calling the functions is this:

```
binarySearch(arr, 1, n, x);
```

and

```
binarySearch2(arr, 1, n, x);
```